# How to create a controller and append an ember view manually?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to learn more about the core of ember by reading the source and unit testing various components. Currently I'm trying to wire up a simple view/controller/template combination to see if I can assert against the view (actual html output) that gets rendered w/ a given model and template.

My first test that does work looks like this

```
it ("template will render given output", function(){
    var view = Ember.View.create({
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('bar')
    });
    Ember.run(function() {
        view.appendTo("#body");
    });
    expect(Ember.$.trim(view.$().text())).toEqual("bar");
  });
```

But this is not doing anything dynamic w/ a model or controller. My next attempt is currently failing because I can't seem to wire in the view (to a given controller).

```
  it ("model property is output when view bound", function(){
    var speaker = CodeCamp.Speaker.createRecord({id: 1, name: 'foobar'});
    var view = Ember.View.create({
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{#each foo in controller}}{{foo.name}}{{/each}}')
    });
    var controller = Ember.ArrayController.create({                                                                                    
        content: []
    });
    get(controller, 'content').push(speaker);
    var x = get(controller, 'content');
    var len = get(get(controller, 'content'), 'length');
    expect(len).toEqual(1);
    set(controller, 'view', view);
    Ember.run(function() {
        view.appendTo("#body");
    });
    expect(Ember.$.trim(view.$().text())).toEqual("foobar");
});
```

But as it stands now the assertion fails

> Expected '' to equal 'foobar'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by this line:

```
set(controller, 'view', view);
```

It has to be:

```
set(view, 'controller', controller);
```

**Summary:** The view has to know about its controller. In your case the view does not have a context to lookup properties and therefore does not work. You accidentally did it the other way round.

**Note:** This applies to Ember-pre4. I tested this fix successfully against it. (I believe the approach to view setup has changed recently)

Comment: nice -didn't realize the set worked this way! thanks for the quick reply